# how to remove file 0= file which has srw permission

Tags: permissions, rm, delete, unix-sockets

How can I remove below file?

```
srwxrwxrwx   1 patroh root           0 Aug  8 16:11 0=
```

The user `patroh` is myself. The `rm` command won't work - it doesn't give any error when I execute `rm 0`.

I am not sure how I created this file?

Comment: "rm command won't work" – What exact command gives you what exact error?

Comment: rm command doen't give any error. when I execute rm 0

Comment: Try `rm ./0=` or `rm -- 0=`

Comment: Do you have write permissions in the directory (folder) where this file is located?

Comment: I assume the `=` is signifying file type, and therefore the file really is called `0`. You could try `rm -i ?` and see what happens.

Comment: The leading "s" and trailing "=" indicate it's a socket file. Try finding the creating (and holding) process with `lsof` or `fuser`. When that process terminates, it might release the socket.

Comment: `rm -rf` removed my file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `s` at the start of the line in `ls -l`'s output identifies that as a unix-domain socket. The `=` at the end is a type indicator for sockets, one that `ls -F` adds. So the file itself is called just `0`.

Unix sockets are a particular method of interprocess communication that mostly acts like real network sockets but have names in the filesystem, which allows the usual filesystem access controls to apply to the sockets. That "file" you have there is one such name.

The socket pseudo-files tend to linger around (uselessly) after the process that opened them has exited, unless something takes care to remove them. But they can be removed like any file. (Well, on Linux, at least.) E.g. with `nc` creating a unix socket and `rm` removing it:

```
$ nc -U -l socket &
[1] 22480
$ ls -l
total 0
srwxr-x--- 1 ilkkachu ilkkachu 0 Aug 10 00:45 socket=
$ rm socket 
$ ls -l
total 0
$ kill %1
```

If `rm` doesn't give an error, it should mean it was able to remove the file. Of course, that wouldn't stop the file from being recreated afterwards.